# A distributed, scale-out quantum computing architecture?

Tags: architecture

Having been part of the mainframe, client-server, and now containers scale out architecture, I can observe the parallel and resemblance of today's quantum computers (massive) to that of the mainframe era where everyone hooks onto this massive mainframe for computational power.

How does one design a fundamentally distributed scale-out quantum computing architecture?

Comment: I'm not one of the three close-voters, and I don't believe much in close-voting without leaving a comment, but I do think it's not clear what you mean. By "distributed scale-out" do you mean "everyone hooks onto this massive quantum computer to use it" ? If so, that's how quantum computers are right now anyway, and the *design* is precisely the same as it is for classical computers, in fact that "distributed scale-out" is done on a classical computer.

Comment: nope, its more like a peer to peer quantum computer. much like how we are communicating now with our laptops or mobile phones.

Comment: Okay, good luck